# Is sodium acrylate soluble in ethanol?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solvents

I am trying to make sodium acrylate by neutralizing acrylic acid with sodium hydroxide. I further want to photo-pattern it, which requires the addition of photoinitiator to sodium acrylate.

The problem is acrylic acid and photoinitiator are soluble in ethanol, but NaOH is not. Hence I'm looking for a common solvent for sodium acrylate and the photoinitiator.

Comment: Try sodium ethoxide or sodium tert-butoxide in EtOH as your base